# Checking instanceof for objects declared differently

Tags: javascript

I'm reading up on how to declare objects in JavaScript.

There is the object literal way and the function based way. In the following code, I create an object called Person1 using object literal, and Person2 using function based.

I then try to check their instances. For Person2, I get "true" but for Person1 I get "TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable"

```
var Person1 = {
  name: "John"
}

function Person2() {
  this.name = "Jane";
}

var bob = Person1;
var bobby = new Person2();
console.log(bob instanceof Person1);
console.log(bobby instanceof Person2);
```

How can I create an object using object literal and still get the correct instanceof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* do it, but you *really shouldn't*. [`Symbol.hasInstance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/hasInstance) allows you to overload the behavior of [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof):

```js
var Person1 = {
  name: "John",
  [Symbol.hasInstance](instance) {
    return instance === this;
  }
}

function Person2() {
  this.name = "Jane";
}

var bob = Person1;
var bobby = new Person2();
console.log(bob instanceof Person1);
console.log(bobby instanceof Person2);
```

However, what you *should* be doing is this:

```js
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

// confusing variable names if you ask me
var bob = new Person('John');
var bobby = new Person('Jane');

console.log(bob instanceof Person);
console.log(bobby instanceof Person);
```

Comment: Makes sense. It just confuses me that I can create objects using two different things but only one of them is an actual instance of it.

Comment: It confuses me that you expect objects created with two different methods to be an instance of the same thing...

Comment: Two different things should be different

Answer (score 1):

`Person1` is reference to `{name: "John"}` `object` not a `constructor` so you can't do `instanceof` on `Person1`

while `Person2` is a `constructor` so you can do `instanceof` on `Person2`.

```js
var Person1 = {
 name: "John"
}

function Person2() {
 this.name = "Jane";
}
var bob = Person1;
var bobby = new Person2("john");
    
console.log(bob === Person1) //true
console.log(bob instanceof Object) //true
console.log(bobby instanceof Person2) //true
console.log(bobby instanceof Object) //true
console.log(bobby === Person2) //false
```